# Make Bootstrap columns with same height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm following this text to make a section of my webpage show all columns with same height: https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-equal-height-columns-d07bc934eb27 
But trying to fit into my CSS logic I can't get it right, my scratch: https://www.codeply.com/go/Bspc3JC2r2

I tried to insert *row display-flex* or just *display-flex* into different places, but didn't work.

I saw some solutions around here(some of them pretty old), but a lot of them are not recommended cause they can break responsiveness. I hope is there a way to fix this, or a better way to do that.

Comment: This should not be a duplicate - yes the other question is regarding equal height columns in bootstrap, but this person's html markup is part of what's causing the issue; question is about potentially applying the fix in their situation, and that it's not working.

Original question: how to do it
This question: trying to do it but it's not working in my case

Comment: I can't post my answer unless @Paulie_D unmarks this as a duplicate, but I forked your code and fixed it:
https://www.codeply.com/go/5Aya9N9XSO

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I wish I could mark as an answer.

Comment: @willanderson's answer is correct